# TinyMCE causing to remove in-line

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, tinymce

I am having issues with TinyMCE and twitter bootstrap: Heres my problem, the sidebar and the content have gone out of in-line. Heres a screenshot: http://puu.sh/GOhR

Code of that page:

```
<?php
//create_cat.php
include 'connect.php';
include 'header.php';

$sql = "SELECT
        topic_id,
        topic_subject
    FROM
        topics
    WHERE
        topics.topic_id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(!$result)
{
echo 'The topic could not be displayed, please try again later.';
}
else
{
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    echo 'This topic doesn&prime;t exist.';
}
else
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        //display post data
        echo '<table border="1" class="table table-bordered table-striped" 
style="float: right; width: 990px;">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">' . $row
['topic_subject'] . '</th>
                </tr>';

        //fetch the posts from the database
        $posts_sql = "SELECT
                    posts.post_topic,
                    posts.post_content,
                    posts.post_date,
                    posts.post_by,
                    users.user_id,
                    users.user_name
                FROM
                    posts
                LEFT JOIN
                    users
                ON
                    posts.post_by = users.user_id
                WHERE
                    posts.post_topic = " . 
mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

        $posts_result = mysql_query($posts_sql);

        if(!$posts_result)
        {
            echo '<tr><td>The posts could not be displayed, please try 
again later.</tr></td></table>';
        }
        else
        {

            while($posts_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($posts_result))
            {
                echo '<tr class="topic-post">
                        <td class="user-post">' .     
$posts_row['user_name'] . '<br/>' . date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime($posts_row
['post_date'])) . '</td>
                        <td class="post-content">' . 
$posts_row['post_content'] . '</td>
                      </tr>';
            }
        }

        if(!$_SESSION['signed_in'])
        {
            echo '<tr><td colspan=2>You must be <a 
href="signin.php">signed in</a> to reply. You can also <a href="signup.php">sign up</
a> 
for an account.';
        }
        else
        {
            //show reply box
            echo '<tr width="640px;" style="width: 10px;"><td 
colspan="2"><h2>Reply:</h2><br />
                <form method="post" action="reply.php?id=' . $row
['topic_id'] . '" style="width: 100%; margin-left: 100px;">
                    <textarea name="reply-content" name="elm1" 
rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%; margin-left: 100px; float: right;"></
textarea><br /><br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit 
reply" /  >
                </form></td></tr>';
        }

        //finish the table
        echo '</table>';
    }
}
}

?>
```

TinyMCE in header.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : 
"autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespel
l,in
linepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,direction
alit
y,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,
auto
save,visualblocks",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : 
"save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,jus
tifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : 
"cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,inden
t,blo
ckquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttim
e,pr
eview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : 
"tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,a
dvhr
,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : 
"insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins
,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft,visualblocks",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,

    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    content_css : "css/content.css",

    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
    template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

    // Style formats
    style_formats : [
        {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
        {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : 
'#ff0000'}},
        {title : 'Red header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
        {title : 'Example 1', inline : 'span', classes : 'example1'},
        {title : 'Example 2', inline : 'span', classes : 'example2'},
        {title : 'Table styles'},
        {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
    ],

    // Replace values for the template plugin
    template_replace_values : {
        username : "Some User",
        staffid : "991234"
    }
});
</script>
```

Could someone please tell me how to fix it or supply me with a code to enter or something like

Comment: I forgot to include that I've tried making the TinyMCE textarea smaller. No effect.

Comment: the image does not show the problem?

Comment: I resolved it. Changing the width of something, I think it was the table.